Select faces directly touching selected edges?
I would love to know a way to select faces that are directly neighbours to selected edges.
Simply using grow selection ("select more" command) does not solve this because it selects all faces connected to vertices of the selected edges, and I just want to select faces that share the selected edges.
Also, this method should work when selected edges are mesh boundary (non-manifold - each edge has only 1 face connected).
In the screenshot, I marked the preselected edges with white, and the desired face selection with red outline. Orange faces selection was achieved by using "select more" command.

Test mesh:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hY5dpSrGJn0y2PewO1-mFf2yafs2uSG/view?usp=sharing

AFAIK this is not possible with vanilla Blender. But it should be possible (quite easy) with a little script/add-on.

I will think about it, but for now I think I might be able to find workaround for it for my case.


Select the starting edges
Shift+LMB the Face Select button to Ensure the Selection Mode includes Faces
Ctrl+NumPad +  or Select → Select More/Less → More
In the popup/F9 or Edit → Adjust Last Operation, uncheck Face Step
Click the Face Select button to remove the Edge Select and so deselect the stray edges
(or Shift+LMB the Edge Select button to toggle it off)

A bit cumbersome, but works in the end and makes a sort of sense. Demo of the above:


Wow, just a bit tricky but working well. Thank you, I wouldn't figure that out by myself. Actually, the second step is redundant, at least in this particular case. We will achieve the same with just the edge selection mode activated (without adding face mode), and the rest goes roughly as you described. Really appreciate! I think I need to relearn Blender checking every command and looking for hidden gems in the Adjust Last Operation box.
